# Drop down list with values from the same record

Tags: database, combobox, ms-access-2016

I'm setting the new database and can't figure out how to make a combo box with values from the same record.
It's about the customers and orders. Customers might have up to 3 delivery addresses. So when a person is raising a new order in a form, he has a drop down list with addresses and can choose one.
In the table I have info. about the customer:

```
CustID | CustName | Addr1 | Addr2 | Addr3
   1   | TestCust |  XXX  |  YYY  |  ZZZ
```

By creating a query I keep getting all three addresses in the same "line/choice".
Or do I need to create this "address book" somehow differently?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(Addr1, ',', Addr2, ',',Addr3) AS Address FROM customer;
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer. But now I keep getting "Undefined function CONCAT in expression" :(

Comment: SELECT *, CONCAT(Addr1, ',' Addr2, ',' Addr3) AS Address FROM customer.        Sorry there were mistek with comma please try this one